# ControlsFX: AutoCompletion bind to a model class

Tags: javafx, binding, autocomplete, controlsfx

I have a model class:

```
public class Client {
    private long id;
    private String name;


    @Override
    public String toString() {

        return this.name;
    }


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

and I have a `Textfield` that I want to use auto complete using a list of `Client` class, using ControlsFX, here is what I did:

```
AutoCompletionBinding<Client> binding = TextFields.bindAutoCompletion(searchField, SuggestionProvider.create(appState.clients));
```

Where `appStat.Clients` is a list of `Client` class. For some reason I get no suggestions appearing. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Whatever you have posted should work. Can you post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Yes it does work, thanks. I made a mistake and the list was empty.